# Comma separated string with H2 Database

Tags: java, database, jdbc, h2

I am writing my test against H2 and using MySQL at production.

I have an entity like this:

```
public class User{
   private Integer id;
   private String username;
   private Set<String> roles;
}
```

What I would like to serializing my set as a comma separated string. I have noticed other_type at h2 document but could not be sure how to do.

Any help?

Thanks

Edit: Actually I am using another library which is based on JDBC. It seems that setObject and getObject method of ResultSet is appropriated but could not be sure how to deal with it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to store `Set<String> roles` as a comma separated list? How large could the list get? If only a few hundred entries, then using `VARCHAR(32000)` might be enough (MySQL supports up to 65536, and there is no limit for H2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use VARCHAR(32000). Both MySQL and H2 support that. Please note 32000 is just the limit, and it doesn't mean that this much space is used.

Comment: Thanks, varchar is suitable for my case but could not figure out how to serialize.

Comment: You mean, how to convert `Set<String>` to a comma separated string?

Comment: I know how to convert but the whole point is I want to use `setObject(myRoleSet)` without converting it myself.

Comment: You can't. `setObject` will use Object serialization for H2, and I don't know what it would do for MySQL. In any case, it doesn't convert it to a comma separated value.